# Circular issue: accessing set of objects from within its own member function

Tags: c++

I am simulating a set of spheres interacting with each other.
For this reason I made a class sphere that stores its position x-y-z and has a method update() that updates its position.

```
class cSphere {
double x; double y; double z;
void update()
}
```

This update function, however, depends on the positions of the other spheres. I am not sure how to best handle this circular problem.

What I tried first was to create a std::vector *vec_spheres in my main() as a global variable and access it within update() by defining extern std::vector *vec_spheres in cSphere.h. This does of course not work though.

I am now thinking about creating a singleton class that returns a pointer to *vec_spheres but that also seems hacky.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: To start try passing the function a vector containing all other spheres - `void update(const std::vector<CSphere>& otherSpheres);`. I don't recommend using a singleton as it hides `cSphere`'s dependency on the list of spheres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the light of LawOfDemeter I don't suggest making that knowledge the responsability of `cSphere::update`.

Instead, make a higher entity (`cSphereSimulation`, `PhysicsEngine`, ...?) that knows how to calculate the new positions of all spheres.

In pseudo code:

```
struct cSimulation
{
    std::vector<cSpheres> _spheres;

    void update()
    {
          // calculations using all positions...
          for (auto& sphere : _spheres)
               sphere.update(newLocation);
    }
    // ...
```